# "That Was Actually My Sick Idea" by Trump

Tags: meaning, trumpism

'THAT WAS ACTUALLY MY SICK IDEA': PRESIDENT TRUMP ON SENDING IMMIGRANTS TO SANCTUARY CITIES

“Last month alone, 100,000 illegal immigrants arrived at our borders, placing a massive strain on communities and schools and hospitals and public resources, like nobody has ever seen before,” Trump said to the crowd. “Now, we’re sending many of them through sanctuary cities, thank you very much.”
“I’m proud to tell you that was actually my sick idea,” the president said.

As I know, when "sick" is used as a slang, it can mean "cool or awesome". So, did Trump mean that was his cool idea or he really meant that was a sick idea?

Comment: upvoted but please provide link to citation IN the question. https://www.newsweek.com/president-trump-sending-immigrants-sanctuary-cities-was-actually-my-sick-idea-1407712 or https://edition.cnn.com/2019/04/27/politics/trump-migrants-sanctuary-cities/index.html

Comment: Who has any idea what Trump means when he opens his mouth?

Comment: This question simply cannot be answered by anyone other than Trump. We can only say what we *guess* he meant. One person will guess that he meant "excellent", another will guess that he meant "in poor taste", and you'll have made no progress. Then a third person will submit that he meant "twisted", and a fourth person will submit that he meant "covfefe", and you'll be worse off than you were at the beginning.

Comment: As the video clip of the relevant part of Trump's speech indicates, his use of "my sick idea" isn't ambiguous at all. The vast majority of the appreciative crowd knew exactly how ironically and self-admiringly Trump intended the expression. And for anyone who might have been slow on the uptake, Trump conveniently prefaced his "my sick idea" phrase with "I'm proud to tell you..." Hard to misread that.

Comment: So, Sven, do you mean Trump intended to mean "that was my excellent idea"?

Comment: Ultimately, yes—he means "That was my excellent idea"—but he guides his listeners to that conclusion along a route that starts with, literally, "That was my twisted/naughty idea." The irony of Trump's "sick" idea is what makes it so clever and praiseworthy in his (and his fans') view. Trump frequently applies the goals and sensibilities of an insult comic to politics: the objective is to captivate his audience with appeals to their shared sense of humor. In essence, he is what you'd get if you made [Don Rickles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Rickles) the most powerful man in the world.

Comment: I had intended to include, in the comment I posted yesterday, a link to the video of the relevant part of Trump's speech so that site visitors could experience the usage—in context—for themselves, but somehow I failed to add a functioning link. In any case, [The Hill](https://thehill.com/homenews/administration/441014-trump-says-us-is-sending-immigrants-to-sanctuary-cities-that-was-my) provides both a 48-second clip from the speech and the text of Trump's wording in that clip.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

**sick**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/179187?rskey=gElMkm&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> colloquial. Of humour, a joke, etc.: macabre, providing amusement by
>   reference to something that is thoroughly unpleasant.

and/or from [Green's Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/6fegq3y):

> - (orig. US) morbid, depraved, e.g. a sick sense of humour. 1961.
>
>   sick and wrong (adj.) (US campus) a general pej., absolutely    impossible, unthinkable, totally disgusting; also used
>     **ironically**. 1989

My sense is that of the ironic, a timely comeuppance.  *“I’m proud to tell you that was actually **my sick idea**”* becomes 'you want a sanctuary city ... you get a sanctuary city.'

Comment: If you read the whole paragraph, he was using it ironically.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh!

The only particularly idiomatic use of "sick idea" in US vernacular is in the often-rhetorical question "Whose sick idea was it to XXX?", where "sick" means "stupid" or "evil" or some such.  In direct response to such a question it would be fairly common to hear "It was my sick idea" from a person who was proud of their decision.

Not having heard the context of Donald's statement it is hard to tell if he was somehow replying to such a question.  And it's hard to guess whether his "base" would understand the reference if the question had not been just posed.  And it's hard to guess whether he understands any of this.

So the question is unanswerable.